# Can someone explain how this code even works?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am reading this function and not at all understanding how this can work.

```
() => console.log(i) || Promise.resolve(i++ > 3)
```

Can a kind soul explain how a console.log can participate in a conditional?

I can even trans-pile this in typescript.

Comment: I mean, it will never go to the Promise part so I'm not sure why it's there...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it does, try it in console.

Comment: Needs some parenthesis... to avoid my confusion... 
`() => (console.log(i) || Promise.resolve(i++ > 3))`

Comment: I'd say this would be better with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which is just as confusing but at least doesn't depend on paying attention to the truthiness of the first operand.  `()=>(console.log(i), Promise.resolve(i++ > 3))`

Comment: Please, please, please don't write your own code this way (I know you didn't write this one).  Multiple statements that are intended to both always execute should be written as two separate statements not jammed into one statement in a shorthand way.  Just because the language lets you do some things doesn't mean you should do them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`console.log(...)` returns `undefined`, which is falsy; so the expression after the or `||` operator will always execute. This is just shorthand for:

```
() => {
  console.log(i);
  return Promise.resolve(i++ > 3);
}
```

Comment: Yes, please edit this answer to have  `return` in it.

Comment: What an eccentric shorthand. I don't see how it would be really useful from the maintainability perspective.

Comment: @adelriosantiago `console.log`s are often used for temporary debugging. In such cases, it's quicker to add the `||` than to wrap the line in `{}`. Bug I agree, this should be avoided in committed code.

Comment: @junvar Interesting theory! I see what you mean. It is like a **console-in-the-middle** thing. It may be useful indeed.

Answer (score 3):

[`console.log(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) returns `undefined`, which evaluates to a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: thank you. So the above mentioned function always return a false and the promise is never resolved. Correct?

Comment: I would expect the promise to be resolved every time, as the conditional will always evaluate it for truthiness.  `false || <something>` will result in `<something>` being evaluated.

Comment: ...but in this case the false has the side effect of logging to the console.